# How to extend "Create with reference" dialog in VA01/02

Tags: sap-erp, dynpro

We would like to extend the "Create with reference" dialog in the transactions `VA01` and `VA02` with an additional tab.
[image]

The functionality is very similar to the tab "Order". When the user clicks on the "Item Selection" button I need to add more data to the next screen.

Is it possible to copy the "Order" tab and adjust it to our requirements?

### Addition:

As suggested I started to modify the function group V45C. But as soon as I add the additional tab the programs logic seems to mess up. As soon as the dialog opens I alsways get an error to enter a reference.
[image]

It turned out to be quite difficult to debug in that place as I can't enter the function code `/h`. I assume that the new corresponding fcode is not handled properly so I get this error message.

Do you have any suggestions on where to handle the new fcode and display the dynpro for the tab?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Concerning this screen specifically, I looked at the code in S/4HANA 1709 and there's no user exit to add a custom tab. If you want to change something, you must do a custom modification. I have no idea about the initialization of screen fields on next screen.

Comment: I had hoped there is a more straightforward way then modifying the screen and adjusting bits and bolts around the program.